# Why is not working the broking line on Answer?

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

Please could you help me?

I am trying to write a text with line break bringing the text from a csv file,

On CSV file we have a text like this:
please Check\n\nyour status is offline

*but the code doesn't break the lines. I want to write like this:

your status is offline'

```
#open csv file
df = pd.read_csv('Respostasauto.csv', delimiter =';')
#Look for the correspondent line
Line = df.loc[df['Question'] == texto2]
Messagetype = Line['Subject'].values[0]
Answer = str(Line['Answer'].values[0])
#line break on answer
for line in Answer.split('\n'):
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(line).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very likely your CSV file has characters \ and `n` in it, hence you would want to try `'\\n'` as the argument to `split`?

Comment: so what does it do then? I'd imagine if the csv is correctly formatted to have newlines in the data pandas would read it correctly, what does the data look like?

Comment: csv file:

the 
line 0:
Question;Subject;Answer
line 1:
1;Doubt;please Check\n\nyour status is offline

Comment: VictorMaihato yeah, that is the literal characters `\ ` and `n` then, valid csv requires quotes to escape special characters. @AnttiHaapala would you like to post an answer with your valid solution?

Comment: you mean all between quotes? or only (\n)?

Comment: Thank you antti-haapala!!! It worked!!! I included: for row in Resposta.split('\\n')

Answer (score 0):

[image: It worked including double \ before n]

The suggestion from antti-haapala worked perfectly, so from now on I can split the text on the same message to make it easy for reading.

Follow the image with my code fixed